# Pandas : finding maximum values for each column in a subset

Tags: python, pandas

In the data frame I have these columns `['Happiness score', 'GDP', 'country name', 'Region']`,I have to create a list of all the regions and for every region I have to find the maximum value of each column and name the corresponding country, I already put the regions in a list with `np.unique(df['Region'])`, but how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby('Region').max('GDP')['GDP']
```